# Trying again Maya Python constraints

Tags: python, maya

I went back to my attempt on adding new attribute to every rig, like I want hand can be constraint to the head and / or to the Body, Hips, etc ...
If I add al the attributes that I want and I go to the other hand or leg etc and add new attributes, everything's fine,
the problem happens when I go back to the first hand for instance, and try to add new attribute, then the script fails because it picks the wrong elements to perform the constraints ...

I tried not to use global variables but I cant figure out how to fix it. I would like to have this little code/snippet that once I add the new attribute and create the constraint etc, it would  clear all the variables or what it needs, in order to avoid conflict

Here's the script which create a GUI with a text field where to enter name of the attribute we want to add and after we select an object (an hand for instance), it add the name etc,
with the second button we select what it need to follow....

````
groups = []
new_group = None
last_added_attribute = None
last_constraint_attribute = None

def add_attribute_and_create_group(*args):
    global groups, new_group, last_added_attribute

    attribute_name = mc.textField(attribute_field, query=True, text=True)
    selected_objects = mc.ls(selection=True)

    for selected_object in selected_objects:
        if not mc.objExists("{0}.{1}".format(selected_object, attribute_name)):
            mc.addAttr(selected_object, ln=attribute_name, at="double", min=0, max=1, dv=0, keyable=True)
            last_added_attribute = "{0}.{1}".format(selected_object, attribute_name)

        group_name = selected_object + "_spaceGrp"
        if not mc.objExists(group_name):
            new_group = mc.group(selected_object, name=group_name)
            mc.xform(new_group, centerPivots=True)
            groups.append(new_group)

    print('Returned object is:', groups)

    # Print attributes of the first selected object
    if selected_objects:
        first_selected_object = selected_objects[0]
        attributes = mc.listAttr(first_selected_object)
        print("Attributes of the first selected object:", attributes)
        if attributes:
            last_added_attribute = "{0}.{1}".format(first_selected_object, attributes[-1])

    return groups, new_group


def create_parent_constraint(*args):
    global groups, new_group, last_added_attribute, last_constraint_attribute

    selected_objects = mc.ls(selection=True)
    if not selected_objects:
        print("Nothing selected.")
        return

    if not new_group:
        print("No group created.")
        return

    group_name = new_group
    prefix = group_name.split("_spaceGrp")[0]
    constraint_name = prefix + "_parentConstraint"

    for selected_object in selected_objects:
        mc.parentConstraint(selected_object, group_name, maintainOffset=True, name=constraint_name)
        print("ParentConstraint created between", selected_object, "and", group_name)

    constraint_node = mc.ls(constraint_name)[0]
    first_selected_object = selected_objects[0]

    mc.select(constraint_node, first_selected_object)
    print("Selected constraint:", constraint_node)
    print("Selecting the first user selection:", first_selected_object)

    # Print attributes of the parentConstraint node
    attributes = mc.listAttr(constraint_node)
    print("Attributes of the parentConstraint node:", attributes)
    if attributes:
        last_constraint_attribute = "{0}.{1}".format(constraint_node, attributes[-1])

    # Connect the last attribute of the add_attribute_and_create_group function
    # with the last attribute of the create_parent_constraint function
    if last_added_attribute and last_constraint_attribute:
        mc.connectAttr(last_added_attribute, last_constraint_attribute)
        print("Connected attributes:", last_added_attribute, "<->", last_constraint_attribute)


# Creazione della finestra
window = mc.window(title="Add Attribute")
mc.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)
attribute_field = mc.textField(text="")
mc.button(label="Add Space", command=add_attribute_and_create_group)
mc.button(label="Parent", command=create_parent_constraint)
mc.showWindow(window)```

thanks in advance 
Flys
````

Comment: actually this is a version with global var... I tried many times I cant figure out the problem even without globals I get the same error

Comment: An easy and recommended way to encapsulate all variables is the usage of a class. Especially with UI's a class is really helpful. And since Maya may use it's own names, a more reliable way to get the objects names is to use the result of a function, e.g. `constraints = mc.parentConstraint(...)`.

Comment: Thank you very much Haggi,
but I've also tried to wrap around a class, but the problem was still there because there is something wrong how im calling the elements inside the 2 functions